# I want to play the next song of the spotify android app from my own app

Tags: android, nfc, spotify

My intention was to have my musicplayer to play the next song when my android phone scans an NFC Tag in my car or somewhere else and since i have no Music on my phone i cannot use the standard Android musicplayer. I got all the NFC stuff working but now i am missing some Code to say the spotify app to play the next song if it is currently playing Music. Is there maybe an Intent i can fire or something else? I have not found anything yet on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you're looking for is me/player/next. Just send a POST request and Connect will skip to the next track.

You can find the documentation here:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/skip-users-playback-to-next-track/

Note that you must be a premium user to use the Connect endpoints.

...

*Edit with examples:*

To send a request in Android, use Volley as described here:

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

You're going to want to use a POST request for this endpoint. Roughly, that may look like this:

```
String url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next";

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Do the thing
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Do the error thing
    }
});
```

As this is an endpoint that requires authentication, make sure you follow the Authorization Guide on the Spotify developer site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am not sure how to use this in my Android Code, could you give me some more help?

Comment: @student Edited.